# Why is .argv_[0] returning undefined when moving yargs config to a separate file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

this might seem like a basic question, but I'm working on a note taking app on a Node course I purchased. My original file that works had yargs defined in the same file as the app, along with all of the commands. I figured this made the file a bit length and cumbersome and I was trying to modularize it a bit and move the actual configuration for the yarg commands I wanted to use in a different file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');



//Application files
const notes = require('./notes.js');
const yg = require('./yargs.conf.js');
var command = yg.argv._[0];

if(command === 'add'){
  var note = notes.addNote(yg.argv.title, yg.argv.body);
  if (note) {
    notes.logNote(note);
  } else {
    console.log("Note title exists")
  }
} else if (command === 'list') {
    var allnotes = notes.getAll();
    console.log(`\nPrinting ${allnotes.length} note(s):`);
    allnotes.forEach((note) => notes.logNote(note));
} else if (command === 'read'){
    var note = notes.getNote(yg.argv.title);
    if (note) {
      notes.logNote(note);
    } else {
      console.log("Note not found");
    }
} else if (command ==='remove'){
    var noteRemoved = notes.removeNote(yg.argv.title);
    var message = noteRemoved ? "Note was removed" : "Note not found";
    console.log(message);

} else {

}
```

this is how I have the code now with my config moved to another file below:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const titleOptions =
{
    describe: 'Title of note',
    demand: true,
    alias: 't'
};
const bodyOptions =
{
    describe: 'Body of the note',
    demand: true,
    alias: 'b'
};


const argv = yargs
.command('add', 'Add a new note', {
  title: titleOptions,
  body: bodyOptions
})
.command('list', 'Lists all notes')
.command('read', 'Reads individual note to the screen', {
  title: titleOptions
})
.command('remove', 'Removes selected note', {
  title: titleOptions
})
.help()
.argv;
```

and when I run the file, using list as the command, I receive the following error from the terminal:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*Hidden*\NodeCourse\notes-node\app.js:16:23)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:618:3
> ```

I can't really figure out where I'm messing up on this. Am I just trying to do something I can't? Or am I just accessing the property incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

yargs directly does not contains your arguments directly, all command line info is inside `argv` property, so your code should be `const argv = yargs.argv` ,

Answer (score -1):

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

const command = yargs(process.argv.slice(2)).argv;

console.log(command);
```

Comment: Can you explain this code a little more please?

Answer (score -1):

"yargs": "^17.6.2"

how to setup the yargs

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vfaQ.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGd3t.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).